# Multiplication speed of zero

Tags: c#

I have the next lines of code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    float variable = 0;

    stopwatch.Start();

    variable *= 2.0f;
            
    stopwatch.Stop();
            
    Console.WriteLine("Speed zero:" + stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    variable = 0.0f;
            
    stopwatch.Start();

    variable *= 2.0f;
            
    stopwatch.Stop();
            
    Console.WriteLine("Speed one:" + stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And this code gives the next result:

> Speed zero:34
>
> Speed one:1

Why multiplication of zero gives so many different result instead of multiplication on none zero variable?

Comment: You can't expect to measure a single multiplication using `Stopwatch` and get worthwhile results. I highly recommend looking up some basic articles about how to create useful benchmarks.

Comment: Exchange the variables and you will have the same result. It has nothing to do with zero actually.

Comment: If you have an actual need for microbenchmarking something, [benchmark.net](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/) comes recommended. It avoids many of the pitfalls inherent in writing them, like the need to repeat them, warmup times, etc.

Comment: The main problem is that a multiplication takes less time than a clock tick lasts. Also starting/stopping the stopwatch also takes some time. See: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html / https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet. This library takes account of these and other effects.